# Vim/gVim 8.1 on Windows 10 won't source $HOME\_vimrc

Tags: windows, vim

I have a `$HOME\_vimrc` present, but it doesn't show up in the output of `:scriptnames`. And when I run `gvim -V`, it reports:

```
could not source "$HOME\_vimrc"
```

The only thing in my `$HOME\_vimrc` is the following line:

```
set packpath+=C:\Users\username\vimfiles
```

In case there was something wrong with that path, I also changed the entire contents of the `$HOME\_vimrc` file to this, with the same result:

```
set number
```

When I run `:echo $HOME` from gvim, it reports my Windows user profile directory `C:\Users\username`. I have a `$HOME\_gvimrc` which it reads fine. My vimfiles directory is at the default `$HOME\vimfiles` which it seems to read fine, because it's sourcing a color scheme from there.

Running `:version` shows the following entries:

```
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"
 3rd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
    [...]
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME\_gvimrc"
    [...]
```

Running `:echo $MYVIMRC` outputs `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc`.

I've tried running as both administrator and my Windows username.

Someone suggested that I run `icacls _vimrc` to see the file permissions. Here's the output:

```
C:\Users\username> icacls _vimrc
_vimrc NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
       BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
       DOMAIN\username:(I)(F)
```

That last entry, `DOMAIN\username`, is the login I'm using to run gVim.

What am I missing?

Comment: Btw, feel free to checkout [vi.se]!

Comment: I actually [posted it](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21692/gvim-8-1-on-windows-10-wont-source-home-vimrc/21705#21705) there first. I didn't get a response right away, figured it was a new community and there'd be more Vim users here, so I posted here as well.

Comment: It’s not *that* new—besides cross-posting makes it harder to collect information in a single spot. But oh well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to define `$HOME` as a Windows environment variable.

See `:h $HOME-windows`

```
                            *$HOME-windows*
On MS-Windows, if $HOME is not defined as an environment variable, then
at runtime Vim will set it to the expansion of $HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH.
If $HOMEDRIVE is not set then $USERPROFILE is used.
```